# How to import templates with sub-templates in a wiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

When i try to copy a template from wikipedia to my own wiki, there is a lot of sub-templates associated with it. Do i have to copy paste each sub-templates associated with it to my own wiki which is using mediawiki?

Comment: Please see [the manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Copying_from_one_wiki_to_another) for instructions on how to export templates and subtemplates (not that many templates from Wikimedia wikis require the Scribuntu extension to work). I'm flagging this as OT, as not programming related

Comment: sorry, should be “note”, not “not”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export and write your template name. you can export anything (article, template, categories, modules, etc.). after download the file your can import it to your wiki via https://yourSiteName.com/wiki/Special:Import.